# Call mySQL Stored Procedure from VBA (Excel 2013)

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, stored-procedures

I am trying to call a mySQL stored procedure from VBA.  The stored procedure functions well within mySQl but I cannot get it to copy the recordset into my target cell in excel.  After this simple test works I would also like to have the VBA code copy a cell (ex. sheet4.cells(5,1) ) and use the copied value as the called procedure's parameter for the query.  I would appreciate any help.

```
Private Sub MySQL_Click()

Dim sSQL As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset  
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection 
Dim cmdObj As ADODB.Command 

 Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
 cn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};" & _
        "SERVER=192.168.0.1;" & _
        "DATABASE=enviroland;" & _
        "USER=enviro_land;" & _
        "PASSWORD=enviro_land;" & _
        "Option=3"

sSQL = "CALL test_proc();"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open sSQL, cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

Sheet2.Range("A1:A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Is there an error? Do you know if you are actually getting any records? are you able to push a record to a pop up box or something? Basically what step between New Connection and CopyFromRecordset do you think is causing an issue.

Comment: The method you have will not work with ADODB Recordsets. You need to Loop through the recordset to get the data, ADODB recordsets are different to DAO.

Comment: I would recommend the following:

`if not rs.eof then
dim var as variant
var = rs.getrows
end if`

And play with the data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..There is no actual error.  I cannot tell if it is getting records.  I have removed the parameters because I was not getting anything.  I was able to pass records using a very simple query but when I added a WHERE statement the data stopped passing.

Comment: I think the call is not being sent to the database using a correct query syntax.  Thank you all again

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the command as stored procedure with parameter `adCmdStoredProc`:

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open sSQL, cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdStoredProc
```